# "If your question is not about...": proposed change to help center text

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic-ness, help-center

Some time ago, Ben Norris proposed here on meta that we [update the help center text to be explicit about what **not** to ask](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/updating-our-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-help-center-page-to-be-explicit). That proposal currently appears to have the community's approval. Several other SE sites explicitly describe what not to ask in their help center text (e.g., [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

This meta post is for gathering feedback on **what, specifically, should be included in this "what not to ask" list**.

Currently, the help center text states:

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor
> - Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher
> - Inner workings of research departments
> - Requirements and expectations of academicians
> - University-level pedagogy
>
> ... then you're in the right place!

I propose to change that last part to

> and your question is *not*
>
> - Academia-specific off-topic type 1
> - Academia-specific off-topic type 2
> - etc.
>
> ... then you're in the right place!

What Academia-specific items should go in that list of questions *not* to ask?

**Update**: the list of "what not to ask" has been incorporated into the [help/on-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page and the [tour](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I think it would be better though to avoid an overly long sentence with two lists and instead append a sentence after “... then you're in the right place!” starting with something along the lines of “However, if your question is:”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to add the following text:

> and your question is *not* ...
>
> - Undergraduate-specific, such that it could not apply to graduate or post-graduate academicians
> - Asking for a university, journal, or research topic recommendation (a "shopping question")
> - About preparation for a non-academic career ("What graduate degree will help me get a job as X?")
> - About the content of your research, rather than the process of doing research
>
> ... then you're in the right place!