# Should my question (How can physicists help in biology...) be reopened?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, scope, vote-to-close

Here is my original question: [How can physicists help in theoretical biology, besides math and fresh perspectives?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34941/how-can-physicists-help-in-theoretical-biology-besides-math-and-fresh-perspecti)

As stated in [jakebeal's answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/where-is-the-line-between-a-question-about-doing-research-and-a-question-abou/1493#1493) in the meta question I ask:

> Your question was then a bit borderline because it asked about classes of content interacting with this idea. I'm pretty liberal about how I think about scope on this site, though, and so tend to feel that if something is borderline but we can answer it well, that it is better to include than to close.

Since there is no other answer, is it safely to conclude that this is the official answer? If yes, should my question be reopened?

Comment: If not, do you have any suggestion for where should I ask? Quora?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, many of the answers are posted in comments rather than answers, which means we can't see who would have downvoted. However, it does appear that there is a sense that the question is off-topic due to it's being about a specific research topic rather than relating to academia itself. Personally, I agree with that assessment. In that vein, I think it's remaining closed is probably the best path on this site.

Regarding other venues, the main one that comes to mind is reddit. Hopefully other people can provide other good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it sounds more like a Quora-question. I mean, it's great, but a bit open-ended [I didn't cast a close-vote, thought].

Alternatively, you can try asking on http://biology.stackexchange.com. But even with that it can be too general - depending on discipline the answer may vary. (In short, it is usually applied mathematics, understanding of models, numerics and analogies from physical system.)